# What is causing multiprocess compilation to fail on Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

Compiler: Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5

I have a project which is vulnerable to corruption errors. This problem is linked to Visual Studio flag /MP. When that flag is set I get error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: path\to\temp\AsmTempFile3: Permission denied

I tried opening project as administrator, doing clean and rebuild - I get the same error.

When /MP flag is not set build completes without errors. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing problematic project with other projects I noticed different flag - /FA.
It turns out Assembler Output flag /FA produced problems when coupled with /MP.
The solution is to remove /FA.